# When is my linq query returning an IEnumerable<short> object instead of an int?

Tags: c#

I'm doing a project where I am trying to convert snake case strings into camel case, but when I run my code CS0029 is thrown. I have no idea why this is happening.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Kata
{
    public static string ToCamelCase(string str)
    {
        string[] strSplit = str.Split(new char[] { '-', '_' });
        // this query is throwing an error
        int firstWordIndex = from s in strSplit
                             where s != "-" || s != "_"
                             select Array.IndexOf(strSplit, s);
        string firstWord = strSplit[firstWordIndex];

        var camelCase = from s in strSplit
                        where Array.IndexOf(strSplit, s) != firstWordIndex
                        select s.Replace(s[0], Char.ToUpper(s[0]));

        return string.Concat(firstWord, string.Join("", camelCase));
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line you are getting error?

Comment: the full message says the problem is on (8, 26) but visual studio says the whole query is the problem

Comment: @Abdus it seems like he's getting an error on the line where he assigns `firstWordIndex`.

Comment: I get a different error: https://rextester.com/HLEFF5816   _"(23:30) Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to 'int'"_ which makes sense because `Where` is a filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
int firstWordIndex = from s in strSplit
                     where s != "-" || s != "_"
                     select Array.IndexOf(strSplit, s);
```

When you Select from an enumerable thing (e.g. an array like Split gives you), you get another enumerable thing *even if you put a where clause that ensures the new enumerable thing will have only one element*

```
var array = new[]{ "a","b","c"}

array.Where(x => x == "a").Select(..) //returns you an "array" with only one element
```

If you want just one thing out of an enumerable, look at something like `First()`

```
    int firstWordIndex = (
        from s in strSplit
        where s != "-" || s != "_"
        select Array.IndexOf(strSplit, s)
    )
    .First();
```

`First()` (and its buddies `FirstOrDefault`, `Single[OrDefault]`, `Last[OrDefault]`) will return you just one `T` out of an `IEnumerable<T>`. They accept a lambda that you could use instead of a Where, too (it would look like `Array.IndexOf(strSplit, strSplit.First(s => s != "-" || s != "_")`)

---

Also want to point out that `s != "-" || s != "_"` is surely true for every string in the world, because `"-" != "_"` - as a human you might say "get every ball out of this box that is not red or blue" but that means `not(red or blue)`, which is equivalent to `(not red) AND (not blue)`.

"not red or not blue" is always true because a red ball isn't blue and a blue ball isn't red, and a green ball is not red also (C# doesn't bother checking if a green ball is blue :D )

Common trap; watch out for it

---

I would have dug deeper into fixing your code, but for what it's worth, if I was writing a camelcaser I probably wouldn't use LINQ at all because there's a great risk it could become a very convoluted, low performance affair; even in the code as you have it, you split, then you loop (LINQ does a lot of looping internally) to find any char that isn't X, then you loop again (Array IndexOf) to find the index of that.. It would be a slight optimization to switch to method syntax, as `Select((element, index) => index)` could be used to return the index of the char without looping again but..

I'd probably lower the whole thing, turn it into a char array, loop over it and if the previous char was Char.IsPunctuation/IsWhitespace and the current char is not, I'd Char.ToUpper it otherwise Char.ToLower it, then remove the spaces.. If they were long strings I'd use a stringbuilder and not insert spaces into it. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.ispunctuation?view=net-5.0